# Turn twitter-urls into list timelines?

Tags: twitter, oembed, http, http-api

I know there's the [oEmbed ability to embed a specific tweet](https://en.support.wordpress.com/twitter/twitter-embeds/), as described in their [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-tweets)... but is there any way to simply get the latest in a particular twitter feed, without setting up an account and looking it up, going to the page's get-embed-code button each time, or setting up api keys?

In other words, turn a list of specific twitter urls into embeds, iframes, listing the feeds.

Answer (score 0):

If the feed from twitter is from a particular URL then it is possible to embed the profile tweeting. But apart from that it is literally impossible to do that.

Comment: Can you "embed the profile" programmatically for any given profile?

Comment: @NoBugs Yes it is possible. You can visit the profile in question via your desktop or laptop. And click on the embed profile button. Its as simple as that